# Maintenance/Repair Tags - Are they necessary?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since this site is one where many questions will likely have at *least* three tags (make, model, part) to begin with, I think it is important to narrow down early which overly-common tags should not be used.  This will help avoid hitting the five-tag cap too often, and also make the site look cleaner.

As a starter, I would suggest that [maintenance](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) tags are redundant of the expressed nature of this site, and should not be used.  There are not currently any [repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) tags out there, but there's a total of six [maintenance](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tags including one which is mis-spelled as [maintainance](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintainance).

Answer (score 5):

I would call those redundant tags, as I discussed here: [Tags are for categorization](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/tags-are-for-categorization).

> **Remove Redundant Tags** — Redundant tags are those that are already implied by the site topic of the site. There's simply no value to tags like [repair], [help], [engine], etc. Even tags like [car] and [truck] are going to have limited value. Efforts to coarsely sub-divide the site like that will fail. Tags are not meant (nor well-suited) for the task of dividing the entire site into large swaths for the purpose of participating in (or ignoring) a broad subject site-wide.

Answer (score 1):

I agree about the redundancy although I think that maintenance can refer to routine auto matters and repair for issues that don't come up on a schedule.