# Precedent for creating new tags, specifically for Karting in this case

Tags: discussion, tags

I did find a list that specifies how tags should be used, found [here](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/tags-are-for-categorization). However, I did not seem to find it explicit on how we should format new tags to make sure many duplicates are not created.

In the case I have now, I would like to create a tag for Go-Karting. Should we be using hyphens where they are used in the spelling of the word, or should we avoid them in case someone misspells words? How about for words such as Go-Karting or Go-Kart which are commonly referred to as Karting or Kart. Should we use these abbreviated terms, or is it in the best interest of the community to keep the original word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In terms of karting specifically, I would vote for "karting".  I almost never hear about "go-karts" anymore except in reference to the karts next to the crazy batting cages that were near our house when I was nine or ten.

Answer (score 1):

I would also say Karting - that is the term used by the UK motorsports governing body (obviously I don't know about other countries).

A lot of terms can be region-specific, c.f. gearbox vs transmission, brake disc vs brake rotor, saloon vs sedan, etc. We do have the ability to create tag synonyms for these sorts of terms, but it does need some care with potentially ambiguous tags - e.g the term 'transmission' is used in the UK to refer to the entire transmission system (gearbox, propshaft, differential and driveshafts), but in the US to refer to just the gearbox.

IMHO it is best to use the existing tag where one exists, otherwise create the most-understood* term as the main tag, and synonyms for regional variations.

*although most-understood is going to depend on the opinion of the original poster - Most of us here will understand most of the variations, but be more familiar with their native one.

Comment: I agree with @Nick_C, to me adding the Go- in front of Karting may confuse non-native English speakers and we can just create a synonym tag for the that term.