# Precedence for New Tags Without Questions?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

AGAIN WITH THE TAGS! LOL!

Yes, still thinking about tags and the data involved with them. I am wondering what is the precedence for creating tags without questions? I have noticed there are some tags which do not have questions involved with them, so assume these were created exterior of user questions. The reason I'm asking this is there are a bunch of tags which could provide information to users, but we only have a small subset of those: the trouble code tag. If you look through the tags, you'd see in the neighborhood of 30 entries, but there are a ton of codes out there, both common OBD-I and OBD-II codes, as well as manufacturer specific codes. If we were to add these codes and fill them in, it could provide a wealth of information to users.

I realize all of this information is available online within arms length of a Google search, but to have it here would help a user stay here. I did find two threads in Meta which sort of apply, but do not really answer this specific question: [Precedent for creating new tags](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/precedent-for-creating-new-tags-specifically-for-karting-in-this-case) and [Tags are for categorization](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/tags-are-for-categorization).

Answer (score 5):

Tags without questions?  Could you cite some examples?  I would nominate those for removal.

However, if some of them are super valuable (as you suggest), I think that they'd be good candidates for a wiki question & answer set.

We are still in beta so there's no reason that we can't throw ourselves a few softballs.  If we manage to attract some more traffic to the site in the process, bonus!

Comment: Well, I feel stupid ... while working in the tags, I noticed a bunch of tags which didn't have the (x2) or (x16) meaning the number of attached threads ... *wellllll* I clicked on a couple of them just now and realized the reason they don't show the (x2 or x-whatever) is because there is a single thread attached. Definitely incorrect what I was saying about about tags without questions. This is what I get for assuming things <forhead-palm-slap>. I believe the rest of my question might hold merit though, just from a knowledge resource standpoint.

Comment: @Paulster2, my suggestion still stands - if you know a lot about the codes (especially those that you might expect to see in a cluster), a wiki question / answer is a good place to write them up.

Comment: Be aware that *single-use* tags are culled after 6 months on the site unless the tag wiki (or excerpt) is filled out - this is done to prevent poor tags too obscure to be removed manually from hanging around forever, but it can trip you up if you're trying to keep tags for niche topics around.